# Can I set typescript to enforce assignment to readonly props in a class constructor

Tags: typescript

```js
class Foo {
  private readonly bar: string
 
  constructor() {
  } // TypeError expected. bar is undefined but should be string.
}
```

^ This currently compiles / succeeds and I'm wondering if there's some setting in `tsconfig.json` that I need to specify to make `tsc` more strict.

Comment: Have you tried `--strict`?  (Or at least `--strictPropertyInitialization`?)  [I see an error](https://tsplay.dev/m0VkDw) that the property isn't initialized.  Is that what you want?

Comment: You might also find [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties) of interest: https://tsplay.dev/wEY93w

Comment: You have to update your json file as follow if you dont have this yet.

`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true
  }
}`